# How to create React Context that passes a function with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-context

I'm trying to pass state's setter function using React Context. However, I get a Typescript error "Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(value: number) => void'." when I try to assign a default value to it.

How can I solve it? Many thanks

context.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Movie } from "./movies.service";

export const MoviesContext = React.createContext<{
    movies: Movie[];
    selectedMovie: number;
    setSelectedMovie: (value: number) => void;
  }>({
    movies: [],
    selectedMovie: 0,
    setSelectedMovie: null, // ERROR IS SHOWN HERE
  });
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './components/Pages/HomePage';
import { Movie, fetchMovies } from "./services/movies.service";
import { MoviesContext } from "./services/context";
import MoviePage from './components/Pages/MoviePage';

const Router = require("react-router-dom").BrowserRouter;
const Route = require("react-router-dom").Route;
const Switch = require("react-router-dom").Switch;

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies()
      .then(setMovies)
      .catch(() => setMovies([]));
  }, []);

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([]);
  const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState(0);

  return (
    <MoviesContext.Provider value={{ movies, selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie }}>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container typography-base">
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/movie/:movieid" >
              <MoviePage />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </div>
    </MoviesContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type expects `setSelectedMovie` to be a function, but you're setting the default value to `null`.  Try providing a default function implementation instead.

```
export const MoviesContext = React.createContext<{
    movies: Movie[];
    selectedMovie: number;
    setSelectedMovie: (value: number) => void;
  }>({
    movies: [],
    selectedMovie: 0,
    setSelectedMovie: () => {},
  });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it still expect a `value:number` param?

Comment: @ksav yes, typescript will enforce that a number be passed in. There's no requirement that the function actually *use* that number though, so `() => {}` is a perfectly fine implementation of `(value: number) => void`.

Comment: Many thanks Matt and Nicholas. Could you explain me why does `() => {}` work?

Comment: `() => {}` is a function that does not return anything (implicitly returns `undefined`).  The type `(value: number) => void` means that it's a function that takes a number as an argument and does not return anything.  Your actual function implementation would have to match the argument type if it makes use of them, but it's not required that you use the parameters.  It's essentially the same as if you defined your function as `(value) => {}`, where you're not using the `value` argument.